# How to show wireframe on shaded object in 3D View?

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

Is it possible to show wireframe on shaded objects in the 3D View?
I'm looking for something like below:

[image]

Comment: Object Properties --> Viewport Display --> Wireframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible using the object properties of your sphere.

Go in the display options under the properties tab of the object and check `Wire` and `Draw All Edges`.

[image: display tab]

This will affect the `Solid`, `Textured` and `Material` view-ports.

Comment: How do I do this in 2.93?

Answer (score 17):

I was looking for the same thing. It would be nuts to have to do this per object. Super simple (in 2.93). See the following image (that I found on a polycount forum [post](https://polycount.com/discussion/212563/toggle-wire-frame-on-shaded-for-blender-2-8)) that illustrates how to turn it on and off simply for everything in your view:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! :-) So glad there is a global setting for this! EDIT: The setting also works "per-viewport", meaning you can have one 3D view with the setting enabled, and one 3D view with it disabled. Super useful! :-)

Comment: @Copperplate Yup! Also the value from 0 to 1, I believe represents the angle from 0 to 180 so that you can selectively only show wireframe depending on if it's at certain angles. It still needs some work https://devtalk.blender.org/t/blender-2-8-wireframes-discussion/666/417

Comment: This should 100% be the selected answer ( for those newcomers stumbling here from Google )